# Resolve one Typesafe Config object with other

Tags: scala, config, typesafe

I want to resolve one `Config` object, say `config1` with other, say `config2`.

The only public API that allows something of the sort is `config1.withFallback(config2).resolve()`. However this adds entries from `config2` to `config1` which is not something we want.

On some investigation, we found a non-public class named `ResolveContext` which provides a method for that. So we are making use of that using reflection. Our current code:

```
object ConfigImplicits {
  implicit class RichConfig(val config: Config) extends AnyVal {
    def resolveWith(source: Config): Config = {
      val resolver = resolveContext.getDeclaredMethod(
        "resolve", 
        abstractConfigValue, 
        abstractConfigObject, 
        configResolveOptions
      )
      resolver.setAccessible(true)
      resolver.invoke(
        null,
        config.underlyingAbstractConfigObject,
        source.underlyingAbstractConfigObject,
        ConfigResolveOptions.defaults
      ).asInstanceOf[ConfigObject].toConfig
    }

    def underlyingAbstractConfigObject = {
      val f = simpleConfig.getDeclaredField("object")
      f.setAccessible(true)
      f.get(config)
    }
  }

  val resolveContext = Class forName "com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext"
  val abstractConfigValue = Class forName "com.typesafe.config.impl.AbstractConfigValue"
  val abstractConfigObject = Class forName "com.typesafe.config.impl.AbstractConfigObject"
  val configResolveOptions = classOf[ConfigResolveOptions]
  val simpleConfig = Class forName "com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig"
}
```

We realize that relying on non-public innards might not be a good idea. So:

1. Is there a public method, that we somehow missed, which already does this?
2. If not, shall we make a pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not AFAIK a public method. A less-fragile workaround instead of relying on private API might be to first resolve with your source object in there as a fallback, then iterate over the keys in the source object you resolved from and just remove those unwanted keys from the target object.

I can't think of a reason not to add a Config.resolveWith(), though I wonder if there was a reason since I do remember considering it. Maybe I just figured nobody would use it.

If you do a pull request, be sure to include tests and docs. I think the pull request is reasonable, assuming it turns out to be very little code (as I would expect). The current master branch is open for API additions, to appear in an eventual 1.2 release.

Comment: It appears some moderator abused his rights and deleted the comment I posted here last time. For the purpose of proper continuation of that communication I will repeat what I had posted (as per what I recall): "Thank you. I will fork and try adding the method and make a pull request if I succeed." As promised, I tried, however the hierarchies seem strangely entangled and I was not able to add the method. [1/2]

Comment: The workaround you suggested did not work for us because the original config already has those keys. We don't want them to be replaced, which is why instead of using `withFallback` we wrote our `resolveWith` (which uses reflection).

Comment: For future bystanders, there's now a resolveWith() API available.